# Table Schema, and Class Definition

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting error when running the login form to enter the values but i got run time exception

> The data types **text** and **nvarchar** are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Where I do some changes to avoid this error.

I have already tried:

```
usertype(datatype("text" to"varchar(MAX)") and( "varchar(50)" to "text"  and varchar(50) to varchar(MAX)"))
```

And vice versa but i still get this error again and again.
instead of this any solution for this query please help me out.

```
class loginDAL
{
    static string myconnstrng = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstrng"].ConnectionString;
    public bool loginCheck(loginBLL l)
    {
        bool isSuccess = true;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstrng);

        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT *  FROM tbl_users WHERE username=@username AND password=@password AND user_type=@user_type";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", l.username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", l.password);
            **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_type", l.user_type); **

             SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();

            adapter.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                isSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isSuccess = false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return isSuccess;
    }
}
```

I expect the output in login form that successfully open not getting run time exception.

Comment: what is the type of column : `user_type` in the SQL and what is the type of ` l.user_type`

Comment: That code implies you're storing passwords as plain text; I hope not.

Comment: The `text` data type is deprecated as well (since 2005, Ifni recall correctly). You should really stop using it and use `varchar(MAX)`, it has a lot more functionality than the old datatype

Comment: i use it varchar(max) but still getting error

Comment: @poojadongre: still you haven't answer my question, what is the type of `l.user_type`

Comment: the type is varchar(MAX)

Comment: Form my understanding, `l.user_type` is a .net variable and you cannot define a .net variable of type *`varchar(MAX)`*  correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: The error implies one of the three sql field definitions is of type text.  If you have control of the schema change those from text to something like varchar(50) or whatever business rules you have in place for the length of a username of password.

Comment: yes sir this is a .net variable and we can not define .net variable of type varchar (MAX)

Comment: i also use varchar(50) but i didnt get any correct output on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing such issues with the datatypes while communicate with SQL make use of `Add` instead for `AddWithValue`, and specify the exact type of column that you are dealing and also care to pass the corresponding .net type also. [This thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) helps you to identify SQL Server Data Type Mappings with .net
 Here is an example for you:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50).Value = l.username; // for NVarChar(50)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = l.password; // for VarChar(50)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_type", SqlDbType.Int).Value = = l.user_type; // for integers
```

Please note: The above specified methods are only examples for using `Add` for different datatypes, you have to choose the correct DataTypes according to the Type of specific column and the type you are passing should also match.

Comment: i provide in user_type like admin and user

Comment: I create one billing system which i have given two user type like admin and user . In admin user_type i provide details of admin login and In user user_type i provide details of user login  .In that login form after entering values as username password and user type after i click on login button that error comes out :
"The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator."

Comment: @poojadongre: that means they type of `l.user_type` is a string and the column `user_type` is of type `VarChar` right? Then this should work `cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = l.user_type;`

Comment: try
            {
                string sql = "SELECT *  FROM tbl_users WHERE username=@username AND password=@password AND user_type=@user_type";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=l.username;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@password",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= l.password;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_type",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= l.user_type;

Comment: @poojadongre: looks good, ideally this should work, please cross check the datatypes of columns as well. or else make use of SQL profiler to get the executing queries and run them manually and verify

Comment: private void btlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e {l.username = txbxusname.Text.Trim(); l.password = txbxpwd.Text.Trim(); l.user_type = cmbxustype.Text.Trim();bool success = dal.loginCheck(l);if(success==true){  MessageBox.Show("Login Successful."); loggedIn = l.username;    switch (l.user_type){  case "Admin":{   frmAdminDashboard admin = new frmAdminDashboard(); admin.Show();  this.Hide(); }  break; case "User": {  frmUserDashboard user = new frmUserDashboard(); user.Show();  this.Hide() } break; default: { MessageBox.Show("Invalid User Type."); } break; }

Comment: @ sujith karivelil user_type is string type

Comment: @poojadongre: from the available information the supplied solution should work. if it is not means you have to verify the following:- 1. The value that you are getting in `l.user_type`, verify that is either `Admin` or `User`. 2. Do SQL profiling and get the executing query and verify that you are executing a valid query. 3. Try executing them manually and observe output.

Comment: can you share your mail id then i will forword you source code about the error